# How to use <a4j:ajax> with <f:selectItems>

Tags: jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I want to write ajax function and pass selected value from select dropdown menu to bean.
This is what I have:

```
<rich:select id="ctpMeasurementUnits"
    value="#{associationBean.selectedMruId}"
    defaultLabel="#{msg['classifier.select']}"
    requiredMessage="#{msg['classifier.measurementUnitRequire']}"
    validatorMessage="#{msg['common.selectIllegalValue']}">
        <f:selectItems
            value="#{measurementUnitsListBean.allMeasurementUnits}"
            var="mru" itemLabel="#{mru.mruName}" itemValue="#{mru.mruId}">
            <a4j:ajax event="change" execute="@this" listener="#{associationBean.onSelectChangeMru(mru)}" />
        </f:selectItems>
    <f:validateRequired />
    <rich:validator />
</rich:select>
```

However, by using this piece of code I am getting an error:

```
<a4j:ajax> Unable to attach <a4j:ajax> to non-ClientBehaviorHolder parent
```

Question: how to use ajax function from `f:selectItems` dropdown menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to attach a4j:ajax to rich:select not f:selectItems

```
<rich:select id="ctpMeasurementUnits"
value="#{associationBean.selectedMruId}"
defaultLabel="#{msg['classifier.select']}"
requiredMessage="#{msg['classifier.measurementUnitRequire']}"
validatorMessage="#{msg['common.selectIllegalValue']}">
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{measurementUnitsListBean.allMeasurementUnits}"
        var="mru" itemLabel="#{mru.mruName}" itemValue="#{mru.mruId}">        
    </f:selectItems>
  <f:validateRequired />
  <a4j:ajax event="change" execute="@this" listener="#{associationBean.onSelectChangeMru(mru)}" />
  <rich:validator />
</rich:select>
```

Comment: If I attach a4j:ajax to rich:select, then it doesn't work (method onSelectChangeMru is never called)

Comment: Then there's a completely different issue causing that @WheelPot . As it stands, this answer directly addresses the issue you reported. Any number of things could be causing your ajax action to not fire. Look in your javascript console and post the listener method here,

Comment: @WheelPot not it that should prevent the execution but get rid of the parameter, by the time the listener executes the value in the bean will already be changed. (The parameter is null anyway).

Answer (score -3):

Change it to

```
<f:ajax>
```

and if you want to use

```
<a4j:ajax> declare an <a4j:region> and write it down within it.
```

Comment: The tags and attribute names used in the question's code snippet indicate that OP is using RichFaces 4.x, and thus not 3.x, as expected by your answer.

Comment: And even if he was using RichFaces 4 *and* wanted to migrate to `f:ajax`, which isn't stated either, this would not solve the problem. In fact it probably wouldn't work at all even if placed correctly.